# Appending Rows to CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Excuse my being a total novice. I am writing several columns of data to a CSV file where I would like to maintain the headers every time I run the script to write new data to it.

I have successfully appended data to the CSV every time I run the script, but I cannot get the data to write in a new row. It tries to extend the data on the same row. I need it to have a line break.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[date, sales_sum, qty_sum, orders_sum, ship_sum]], columns=['Date', 'Sales', 'Quantity', 'Orders', 'Shipping'])
df.to_csv(r'/profit.csv', header=None, index=None, sep=',', mode='a')
```

I would like the headers to be on the first row "Date, Sales, Quantity, Orders, Shipping"

Second row will display the actual values.

When running the script again, I would like the third row to be appended with the next day's values only. When passing headers it seems it wants to write the headers again, then write the data again below it. I prefer only one set of headers at the top of the CSV. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if I completely understood what you are trying to do, but checking the documentation it seems that you have a header option that can be set to false:

https[://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html][1]

```
Header : bool or list of str, default True
Write out the column names. If a list of strings is given it is assumed to be 
aliases for the column names.

Changed in version 0.24.0: Previously defaulted to False for Series.
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the main dataframe with the colmns you want.
then for each day you create a dataframe of only the new rows then append it to the main row.
Like this :

```py
Main_df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns)
New_rows = pd.DataFrame(new_values, columns)
Main_df = Main_df.append(New_rows, ignore_index=True)
```

For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
print(df)
#   A  B
#0  1  2
#1  3  4

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))

df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
#   A  B
#0  1  2
#1  3  4
#2  5  6
#3  7  8
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply man. I guess I just don't understand the logic. I just want headers on my csv file that won't be overwritten or be duplicated when appending rows when I run the script everyday. I tried typing in the headers manually into the csv file, then running the script, but it starts appending at the end of the row.

Comment: You just need to hold a list of your headers, and use it everytime you are having new rows, the method "append" won't duplicate your headers if they are the same, try it out, it should work like the example.